# How to copy data from old json to new json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

i have a json. i need to copy the content of "data" if provider is "AXIS DATA" to a new json file. How?

what i have tried is

first i convert with `json.parse` and searching it with for loop.

this is my code so far

```
var hasilsearching = {};
var hasildata = JSON.parse( FIRST JSON );
for (var i=0 ; i < hasildata.data.length ; i++){
    if (hasildata.data[i].provider == "AXIS DATA") {
        hasilsearching = hasildata.data[i];
    }   
}
```

but not what i expected. I know inside the `if()` is the problem. but i dont know.

this is my json file

```
{
    "errNumber": "0",
    "userID": "EKL0003097",
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "BXD1",
            "price": "15000.00",
            "name": "Voucher Axis Aigo 1GB 24J 30H",
            "ep": "770",
            "isActive": "Active",
            "type": "KUOTA",
            "provider": "AXIS DATA"
        },
        {
            "code": "BXD2",
            "price": "25000.00",
            "name": "Voucher Axis Aigo 2GB 24J 30H",
            "ep": "660",
            "isActive": "Active",
            "type": "KUOTA",
            "provider": "AXIS DATA"
        },
    {
            "code": "BOLT1",
            "price": "31000.00",
            "name": "Bolt Kuota 1,5GB 24Jam 30hr",
            "ep": "1320",
            "isActive": "Active",
            "type": "KUOTA",
            "provider": "BOLT"
        },
        {
            "code": "BOLT3",
            "price": "50000.00",
            "name": "Bolt Kuota 3GB 24Jam 30hr",
            "ep": "1127",
            "isActive": "Active",
            "type": "KUOTA",
            "provider": "BOLT"
        }
    ],
    "respMessage": "PROSES BERHASIL"
}
```

this is expected new json file

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "BXD1",
            "price": "15000.00",
            "name": "Voucher Axis Aigo 1GB 24J 30H",
            "ep": "770",
            "isActive": "Active",
            "type": "KUOTA",
            "provider": "AXIS DATA"
        },
        {
            "code": "BXD2",
            "price": "25000.00",
            "name": "Voucher Axis Aigo 2GB 24J 30H",
            "ep": "660",
            "isActive": "Active",
            "type": "KUOTA",
            "provider": "AXIS DATA"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `hasilsearching = hasildata.data[i];` should be `hasilsearching['data'][] = hasildata.data[i];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an empty array to the `data` property of `hasilsearching`, and `push` any matches on:

```js
var hasildata = {"errNumber":"0","userID":"EKL0003097","data":[{"code":"BXD1","price":"15000.00","name":"Voucher Axis Aigo 1GB 24J 30H","ep":"770","isActive":"Active","type":"KUOTA","provider":"AXIS DATA"},{"code":"BXD2","price":"25000.00","name":"Voucher Axis Aigo 2GB 24J 30H","ep":"660","isActive":"Active","type":"KUOTA","provider":"AXIS DATA"},{"code":"BOLT1","price":"31000.00","name":"Bolt Kuota 1,5GB 24Jam 30hr","ep":"1320","isActive":"Active","type":"KUOTA","provider":"BOLT"},{"code":"BOLT3","price":"50000.00","name":"Bolt Kuota 3GB 24Jam 30hr","ep":"1127","isActive":"Active","type":"KUOTA","provider":"BOLT"}],"respMessage":"PROSES BERHASIL"};

var hasilsearching = { data: [] };
for (var i=0 ; i < hasildata.data.length ; i++){
  if (hasildata.data[i].provider == "AXIS DATA") {
    hasilsearching.data.push(hasildata.data[i]);
  }   
}

console.log(hasilsearching);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

It's also much easier to use `filter`:

```js
var hasildata = {"errNumber":"0","userID":"EKL0003097","data":[{"code":"BXD1","price":"15000.00","name":"Voucher Axis Aigo 1GB 24J 30H","ep":"770","isActive":"Active","type":"KUOTA","provider":"AXIS DATA"},{"code":"BXD2","price":"25000.00","name":"Voucher Axis Aigo 2GB 24J 30H","ep":"660","isActive":"Active","type":"KUOTA","provider":"AXIS DATA"},{"code":"BOLT1","price":"31000.00","name":"Bolt Kuota 1,5GB 24Jam 30hr","ep":"1320","isActive":"Active","type":"KUOTA","provider":"BOLT"},{"code":"BOLT3","price":"50000.00","name":"Bolt Kuota 3GB 24Jam 30hr","ep":"1127","isActive":"Active","type":"KUOTA","provider":"BOLT"}],"respMessage":"PROSES BERHASIL"};

var hasilsearching = { data: hasildata.data.filter(({ provider }) => provider == "AXIS DATA") };

console.log(hasilsearching);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, its worked. Use filter is great.

Comment: hey, sorry for late response. When i use filter in answer above, i get a warning message. It says 'destructuring binding' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') and 'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6')

how i get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply filter your data like that:

```
let filteredData = hasildata.data.filter(x => x.provider=='AXIS DATA');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the forEach loop

```js
var data={
    "errNumber": "0",
    "userID": "EKL0003097",
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "BXD1",
            "price": "15000.00",
            "name": "Voucher Axis Aigo 1GB 24J 30H",
            "ep": "770",
            "isActive": "Active",
            "type": "KUOTA",
            "provider": "AXIS DATA"
        },
        {
            "code": "BXD2",
            "price": "25000.00",
            "name": "Voucher Axis Aigo 2GB 24J 30H",
            "ep": "660",
            "isActive": "Active",
            "type": "KUOTA",
            "provider": "AXIS DATA"
        },
    {
            "code": "BOLT1",
            "price": "31000.00",
            "name": "Bolt Kuota 1,5GB 24Jam 30hr",
            "ep": "1320",
            "isActive": "Active",
            "type": "KUOTA",
            "provider": "BOLT"
        },
        {
            "code": "BOLT3",
            "price": "50000.00",
            "name": "Bolt Kuota 3GB 24Jam 30hr",
            "ep": "1127",
            "isActive": "Active",
            "type": "KUOTA",
            "provider": "BOLT"
        }
    ],
    "respMessage": "PROSES BERHASIL"
}
var d={data:[]}
data.data.forEach(e=>{
if(e.provider=="AXIS DATA")
d.data.push(e)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to push your fields to an array use the following :

```js
var data = [];
for(var el of myjson.data){
  if(el.provider === "AXIS DATA"){    
    data.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(el)));
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work - `myjson.data` is an *array of objects*, not a single object. This is why some kind of loop is required.

Comment: @JackBashford thank you for pointing that, i updated my answer